# What does [O] denote in organic redox reactions?

Tags: organic-chemistry, redox

I've seen a few examples in the lectures we've been having and I wasn't able to find any sources talking about it. I think I remember a previous teacher saying it was a symbol for oxidation itself, but I doubt this is true.

Said examples from the lectures:

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]

Comment: Could be, but I’m not sure. I’ll wait to see if an answer gets posted

Comment: Your memory is correct - it is a symbol for an oxidation

Comment: [O] is representing an oxidising agent